# Search results to display only results that match all terms

Tags: php, search

I'm new to programming php beyond manipulating prewritten scripts and after a lot of reading, and lessons on php searches, I cannot find a name for, or solution to this. Using hashtags as an example since ultimately that's what I want to use, I'm looking to have a search page where if you were to search for #php #stackoverflow #search then it would only bring up results that contained **at least** those 3. So a result with only #php #search, or #php #stackoverflow would not come up because they're both missing one of the terms from the criteria.

The idea is for it to search my own database not through an API or another sites DB.

I apologize if this isn't the right way to ask/use stackoverflow, I've never posted here, only browsed and read.

To simplify; is there a name/example someone could share with me for when you require all search terms to be matched?

Comment: use AND in your db query

Comment: what is the backend db that you are using ? What is your database query logic here ?

Comment: I think we'd need a bit more information about the backend of your application.

Comment: Unless someone recommends otherwise I was going to use MySQL since I'm most familiar with it. I don't have much info (I know I'm not making this easy but I'm trying) I am actually not even set on php it's just the one I thought made the most sense. I don't know much about the application, I mainly just know I want to be able to use multiple search terms for searches and have them be a required presence for the results to come up. Sorry if this is extremely limited, I'm learning while experimenting. So terminology isn't my strength right now.

Comment: Ok, so it appears that it's just considered multiple value matching? Where LIKE %#hash1% AND LIKE %#hash2% AND.. where the ANDs tell it to return a row only if all three substrings are present? Does that make sense?